# Convergence of a sequence $x_{n+1}=p+\frac{1}{x_{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm attempting to prove the convergence of the sequence $\{x_n\}$, given by

$x_{n+1}=p+\frac{1}{x_{n}}$
with $x_1=1$ and $p>0$

My Attempt: 
$a = p+\frac{1}{a} $  => $a=\frac{p+\sqrt{p^2+4}}{2}$ $(x_n > 0)$

$|x_{n+1}-a|=|p+\frac{1}{x_n}-a|=\frac{a-p}{x_n}|x_n-a|=\frac{(a-p)^{n}}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}|x_1-a|<(a-p)^{n}|x_1-a|$ 
$(a-p) < 1 $ => $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(a-p)^n = 0$ 
=> $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}x_n=a$

To prove the above, i need to first prove $x_n>1$. I know it's right, but i cant prove it.

Any help for $x_n>1$, or any other way to prove the convergence. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prove $x_n> 1,  \frac{1}{x_n}> 1-p$ at the same time. $n=2$ case is trivial. Suppose this is true for $x_n$, then $x_{n+1}=p+\frac{1}{x_n}> 1$, and $\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{p+\frac{1}{x_n}}> \frac{1}{1+p}> 1-p$. By induction we are done.

Comment: The same method using induction from $2$ would prove the strict inequality.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: denote $x_n= a_n/a_{n-1}$ with $a_0 =a_1 =1$ then $$\iff \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= p+ \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}\iff a_{n+1}=pa_n+a_{n-1}\tag{1}$$ and we can find easily the closed-form solution of $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha>0,\beta<0$ be the two roots of
$$x=p+\frac1x\iff x^2-px-1=0.$$
i.e.
$$\alpha=\frac{p+\sqrt{p^2+4}}{2},\quad \beta=\frac{p-\sqrt{p^2+4}}{2},$$
and then
$$\alpha-p=\frac{1}{\alpha},\quad \beta-p=\frac{1}{\beta},\quad
\left|\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right|<1,$$
$$\frac{x_n-\alpha}{x_n-\beta}
=\frac{p+\frac{1}{x_{n-1}}-\alpha}{p+\frac{1}{x_{n-1}}+\beta}
=\frac{\frac{1}{x_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\alpha}}{\frac{1}{x_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\beta}}
=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\cdot\frac{x_{n-1}-\alpha}{x_{n-1}-\beta}
=\cdots=\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{n-1}\cdot\frac{1-\alpha}{1-\beta}.$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n-\alpha}{x_n-\beta}=0\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\alpha.$$